# Fix Ubuntu 20.10 GRUB error installing.Fatal error

Tags: grub2, system-installation, usb-installation

I keep getting the grub install "fatal error" while trying to install Kubuntu. It's a Kubuntu 20.10, no dual boot, but can't erase my home partition (I have my main documents there) to have a fresh install and won't erase it. Already tried the "boot-repair" fix, changing from compatibility boot to uefi, and the best I could get was a black screen with the mouse arrow in it but no response to any key or whatsoever. 3 days now lost trying to get this installed...

UPDATE: after installing GRUB manually using this tutorial using the terminal mode https://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/
Managed to boot but got stuck in "emergency mode".

UPDATE 2: After modifying /etc/fstab (don't know why but it pointed boot to my usb stick plugged during installation ? ), Managed to boot but into X but hanged... Just shows mouse arrow and nothing else...

Comment: Please provide details of what the fatal error is.

Comment: Sorry... Grub won't install that's the error... That's almost all the detail you will get from the installer...

Comment: Please provide information on your partition scheme. I imagine you have a separate /home partition which you are trying to preserve. The rest may be overwritten without any issues, right?

Comment: Yes, but the problem seems to be that the installation writes in fstab that /boot was in /dev/sdb. Fixed it following that tutorial correcting fstab and that was it.

Answer (score 0):

**I fixed it following the tutorial posted in the body of the question. Correcting the /etc/fstab scheme with my hard drive partitions and rebooting. The Graphic system crashing in the boot up seems to be a Kubuntu known issue. Thancks to everyone.**